# Screen resolution, refresh rate and X screen settings keeps getting overwritten even after trying all recommended solutions

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg.conf

As many probably already are aware, this is a persistent problem that still doesn't seem to be fixed. Unfortunately, this is a laboratory machine that needs to be run on a dual screen setup (two seperate X screens) and I have been trying to get this fixed for quite a while to no avail. I have tried all the listed solutions on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316338&highlight=monitors.xml as well as https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217962&highlight=monitors.xml but none of them works.

The CRT monitor (2nd monitor) keeps getting reset to a default setting of 1600x1200 at 75Hz when I needed it to be 1152x864 at 100Hz. Furthermore, the two screens are currently running on the same X screen 0, when I need the CRT to be 1 and the main display as 0.

The closest solution was to amend ~/.config/monitors.xml . I was able to set the CRT to the desired resolution and refresh rate but monitors.xml does not allow me to specify different X screens for the two monitors, at least, I am not aware of the syntax to do so. Removing monitors.xml results in the CRT monitor restored to the default. One question in mind here is that, is there another program that is responsible for applying this default setting? Because I did realise that when there was a monitors.xml present, when ubuntu loads to the login screen, the CRT resolution was initially set to default, before settings from the monitors.xml was applied a second or two later (ie. the screen automatically switched resolution and refresh rate mid-way at the login screen, presumably this is when monitors.xml settings are applied).

I'm keeping my fingers crossed that somehow, someone has got that elusive solution to this because I really need to get this fix asap.

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04, Nvidia Quadro 2000M with Nvidia driver version 375.26.

Appreciate any help I can get.